# SQL Server Profiler - Textdata On 'Prepare SQL' and 'EXEC Prepared SQL' Commands Blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, profiler

I have inherited an application that uses SQL Server as it's database.
To understand the tables accessed from the application when doing specific tasks in the closed code application I usually use SQL Profiler to identify the table and queries performed behind the scenes for each function ( for example adding a customer ).

However with this application all the SQL statements issued are 'Prepare SQL' and 'Exec Prepared SQL' both of which on this application return nothing in the 'TextData' column which usually shows the SQL commands performed.
The login events are also not shown and all SQL statements are shown in profiler attributable to the applications service account.   I have therefore deduced users sign on to the application but the application communicates with the database via the service account and the SQL statements are hidden somehow.

Does anybody know how to expose/reveal the TextData column contents on the 'Prepare SQl' and 'Exec Prepared SQL' statements so I can see which tables the application is using?   I know there are lots of packages out there that claim they can do this but I suspect they are just using the same information as profiler so won't show anything extra.

Comment: Just wondering whether you already selected the SQL:StmtStarting under TSQL and SP:stmtStarting under Stored Procedures in EventSelection tab of the Trace properties?

Comment: You have identified something subtle I had not spotted.

Comment: I had selected TSQL only statements.  If I select 'Stored Procedures' statements as well I do indeed start to see SQL statements in the 'TextData' fields so the SQL isn't hidden as such - I was just selecting a partial list of the SQL statements to include in the trace.  Thanks for your help.  :o)

Comment: Hi Skittle. Happy to know that my comment helped you  some way. If so, you might mark my comment as useful, so that it might help somebody in future. Thanks Shammas

Comment: Be happy to do that but I can't see how to do it?

Comment: Just noticed that you might not have enough reputation yet to flag that. I posted this as an answer. You might accept my answer, if it was useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the SQL:StmtStarting under TSQL and SP:stmtStarting under Stored Procedures in Event Selection tab of the Trace properties.

This way you can make you don't miss any statements in the Text Data.